# SDKs for kiosk software development

Tags: sdk, credit-card, kiosk, cardreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kiosk software guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167015/kiosk-software-guidance)

What kiosk SDKs are available? Are there any? I am looking for ones that saves development time by having built in API integration with hardware (i.e. credit card readers, printers) and network capability (to send data to web app). Also, I would like built in features that check to see if the kiosk has crashed and timers which can inform the software of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

For peripherial compatibility you may be looking for XFS or J/XFS middleware.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEN/XFS